# tune2fs for f2fs

Tags: filesystems, tuning, f2fs

Is there a tool for editing (and viewing) the file system features for f2fs just like tune2fs for ext234?
For instance you can get summarized info about the corresponding extX partition:

```
 # tune2fs -l /dev/path/to/disk
```

To enable checksums on an existing ext4 filesystem:

```
# tune2fs -O metadata_csum /dev/path/to/disk
```